# Difference between SUBSTRING() and RIGHT() functions in SQL Sybase?

Tags: sql, substring, sybase

I have seen in the code that previous developers used this method to get the partial number of the `id`. Here is example:

```
SUBSTRING(rec_id, 4, 1)
```

The `rec_id` columns is `varchar(4)`. I was wondering if there is any difference if I use

```
RIGHT(rec_id,1)
```

Is there any difference in performance? Or anything else that I'm not aware of.

Comment: A big difference.  The first gets the fourth character.  The second gets the last character.  They are only the same if `rec_id` has four characters.

Comment: @GordonLinoff In this case `rec_id` column is `varchar(4)` so sub string is always looking in the last character. I do not see why `right()` is any different in this case.

Comment: It’s variable length so RIGHT will work with shorter strings

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Which method you would recommend if I do `Left Outer Join ON CONVERT(varchar(1), type_id) = SUBSTRING(rec_id, 4, 1)`?

Comment: Since rec_id is declared to be of varying length then I would use RIGHT but that being said I don’t really know how SUBSTRING behaves if the second argument is larger than the string length.